# How to force Samsung Galaxy Tab to shutdown?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, shutdown

My Galaxy Tab P1000 just hung up, at a point where the power button is not responding. Is there a way to force the devise to shutdown immediately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "force shutdown" as far as I know, but you can force a reboot by holding down the power button for about 15 seconds.

Comment: Confirmed that this also works for the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0.

Comment: Did not work for Galaxy Tab S5e. Had to hold down both Power button and Volume Down button for 10+s. (I was setting up fingerprint with pin code, I had set up the pin, but exited out of the fingerprint setup and locked the screen... there were no pin pad or keyboard on the unlock screen and nothing happened when I tapped on the normal restart or shutdown... after the reboot the pin pad showed up and I was able to unlock it... and remove the pin code. What a wonderful QA tested product...)

Answer (score 13):

For Tab S and Tab A
and Tab gt-5100
Should work with 8.4 or 10.5

Hold the Power button, Volume Down button, and Menu key for 10 seconds.
You will enter download mode, simply press the volume down button to restart tablet.

After reboot, you tablet should perform as normal

Comment: For my SM-P550 (Samsung Galaxy Tab A with S Pen 9.7") the key combination is Volume Down button, Power button, and Home button for 10 seconds.

Comment: This worked with my son's SM-380 tablet.  It certainly beats waiting for the battery to run dead!

Comment: Thanks,  Volume Down + Power button worked on Galaxy Tab S5e.

Answer (score 9):

No force shutdown for galaxy tab, but you can use this trick.

1. Plug the charger into your galaxy tab.
2. Hold down power button for 10 seconds, and wait to reboot.
3. After that, the screen will be change with charging battery.
4. Plug off your tab, and it will be shutdown.

Comment: This should be chosen as answer because it really does what the asker wants. I can confirm it works on Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 P5100

Comment: The right answer for a bootlooping device