# Samsung Note 10.1 (2014) tablet discharges when powered off

Tags: samsung, tablet, standby, shutdown

My samsung tablet discharges when powered off and not connected to a charger. It's too fast that i would suspect some battery self-discharge.

I am not totally sure about the state of the power-off mode, because when powered off it still displays a battery symbol, when i press the power button a short time (and switches off the display again when i press the button again).

How can i shut it down, so that it's fully off? Long Pressing Power while booting just gets it in the same state again or only reboots again.

Comment: Try this to force [shut down](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/38492/131553)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Long pressing power? I tried that. What seems to work (from screen state, need to check if from battery) is booting up to the disk encryption password prompt and then shutting down from there.