# Lost password on Galaxy S2, can't shut down

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, tablet, password

My new Christmas Galaxy Tab S2 7":
I was prompted to download an updated OS. I did so successfully and was prompted to restart. Okay, now I need my password.  That is *ONLY* the password works, since the fingerprint won't work until the TAB is restarted after the update.  But what *WAS* my password???  The information on the web says I can factory reset easy enough, but step one is to shut it off.  I can't do that without getting past the password input stage.  So far my Galaxy is a lovely-to-look-at, high tech paperweight.

So how do I either force it off so I can continue with a factory reset (including password) process, or go from where I am (at the password input stage) to a factory reset?  (I think the password was among the Christmas wrapping that went as smoke up the chimney.)

Comment: See also the following question which is identical just for another Samsung tablet: [How to force Samsung Galaxy Tab to shutdown?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20264/how-to-force-samsung-galaxy-tab-to-shutdown)

Answer (score 1):

To force the Galaxy Tab E to restart, hold the <kbd>power</kbd> and <kbd>volume down</kbd> keys for around 20 seconds. This has the same effect as physically removing the battery. If this does not work, attempt holding all four physical buttons for 20 seconds. After the device is turned off, start it up in the recovery mode by holding <kbd>volume up</kbd> + <kbd>home</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd>. Highlight `Wipe data/factory reset` with the volume keys and select it using the <kbd>power</kbd> button. Select `Yes` and the tablet will be restored to factory specifications. Finally, select `Reboot system now` to restart the device.
During the setup process, Factory Reset Protection may kick in. Log in to the Google Account previously used on the device to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

To force your tablet to shut off, press and hold the power button for 20-30 second until it fully shuts off.

You can then follow the steps [here](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-129433/) to factory reset it.

Usually the backup password is something that you would set up when setting up your device, and not something that would arrive with your tablet. So i suggest you first try some passwords that you might have used as a backup password.

Comment: Thank you however this does not work. I tried the on/off switch and also that and the volume button it will not shut down without the passcode.

Comment: Sorry - holding down the power key for over a minute the Tab E does not shut-off.

Answer (score 0):

Press the restart button instead of off button ( it wont ask for password this way) then quickly do the 3 key combo

Comment: Welcome to the Android SE! What is that "3 key combo"?

Comment: I'd assume the power+vol. up+vol. down buttons, but OP's clarification would help. On the other hand, Samsung Galaxy Tab has an exclusive restart button? Or is that selection on the power menu instead?