# Galaxy Tab E won't turn off

Tags: samsung

My grandson added a passcode to my Samsung Galaxy Tab E and can't remember it. I cannot shut it off to do a factory reset. Please help I am a dummy at this also. Thanks

Comment: Please check out https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188505/lost-password-on-galaxy-s2-cant-shut-down?rq=1 answer, hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Hold power and volume down (this simulates battery disconnect).
Once the screen shuts down, press (and hold) volume up, home, and power.
It will boot into recovery mode.

Comment: Mine doesn’t go into recovery mode  so I’m literally stuck and not able to get into my son’s tablet.

Comment: Any other suggestions? Holding the power and volume down restarts it immediately, it does not power it down. And there is no home button.